# Cross object picklist validation rule

Tags: picklist, validation

This does not seem to be working.  Checking the syntax does not give me an error.  As I can successfully query for the values inside the quotes (i.e., Member, Voting Member), these values are valid.

I could not find any example like this so maybe it has to be structured a different way?

```
AND(
  NOT(ISPICKVAL(Voting_Member__r.Type,"Member")),
  NOT(ISPICKVAL(Voting_Member__r.Member_Status__c, "Voting Member"))
)
```

Comment: What is your requirement? Something like if Voter Member Type is Member or Member Status Voting Member, you want to allow insert/update else block? You can phrase this like below,

NOT(AND(ISPICKVAL(Voting_Member__r.Type, "Member"),ISPICKVAL(Voting_Member__r.Member_Status__c, "Voting Member"))) If you provide clarity on your requirement would be able to help.

Comment: The requirement is to only allow a company where it is type is a member and a member status is voting member..  The field being validated is a lookup(Account) and the two values are both picklist values in the account object.  The field being validated is a related object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to allow only a company where type is `Member` and member status is `Voting Member`, then your validation rule should be

```
NOT(
    AND(
        ISPICKVAL(Voting_Member__r.Type, "Member"),
        ISPICKVAL(Voting_Member__r.Member_Status__c, "Voting Member")
    )
)
```

The problem with your current validation rule is you are having `AND` conditon which means the rule will fire only when both the criteria matches, whereas you want the rule to fire when either of them does not match. You also can use `OR` like below which will evaluate to same as above mentioned condition.

```
OR(
    NOT(ISPICKVAL(Voting_Member__r.Type, "Member")),
    NOT(ISPICKVAL(Voting_Member__r.Member_Status__c, "Voting Member"))
)
```

Comment: Well explained and it makes perfect sense now.  Thank you Vijay!

Comment: @Daryn Glad to help you !